# C# Marshal.SizeOf

Tags: c#, size, marshalling

I am using Marshal.SizeOf to know the size of my stucture:

```
struct loginStruct
{
    public string userName;
    public string password;

    public loginStruct(string userName, string password)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Here is the use of this function:

```
int len = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(loginStruct));
```

I got 2 programs. In one program len is equals to 8. In the other it equals to 16.
It is the same struct. Why I got that differece?

Comment: Note that since .NET 4.5.1 you can write that as `int len = Marshal.SizeOf<loginStruct>();`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd guess one program is compiled for AnyCPU (which on a 64-bit platform will be 64-bit) and one for 32-bit.

Comment: Yep, you can verify this by changing the platform target and recompiling.

Comment: And isn't it possible to use fixed char[] arrays if you are OK w/ unsafe code? I think so

Answer (score 5):

Methods don't affect the size given, so effectively we're talking about:

```
struct loginStruct
{
    public string userName;
    public string password;
}
```

That `struct` has two reference type fields. As such, it has two fields in the memory which refer to objects on the heap, or to `null`.

All reference type fields are 4 bytes in 32-bit .NET and 8 bytes in 64-bit .NET.

Hence the size would be 4 + 4 = 8 in 32-bit .NET or 8 + 8 = 16 in 64-bit .NET.

Answer (score 1):

It is depending on the machine and on the build configuration.
As @Joey said AnyCPU or 64-Bit

There are some tricks to avoid this problem:

For example you can check:

- The application type Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
- The size of IntPtr changes on 32 and 64
- using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA)